# Can you recommend a good asset management and issue tracking system?

Tags: issue-tracking

Our company is looking to replace our dated issue management software, currently evaluating Atlassian JIRA which is a fantastic issue management system. However our current issue management system also has asset management.

Could someone recommend and asset management plugin to JIRA or a different system?

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/product/). I have not configured it before but have had a play around and they seem pretty usable as an almost automated asset management system. It is free so you can trial it out.

Comment: I like the look of it

Answer (score 0):

While a SaaS based solution I'm associated with is not open source, it fits your needs for asset tracking. Using the API's you can integrated with JIRA as well. Take a look at [ezofficeinventory](http://www.ezofficeinventory.com).